# "cannot move out of borrowed content" when replacing a struct field

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider this example:

```rust
struct Item {
    x: u32,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn increment(self, amount: u32) -> Self {
        Item { x: self.x + amount }
    }
}

struct Container {
    item: Item,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn increment_item(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        // This line causes "cannot move out of borrowed content"
        self.item = self.item.increment(amount);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Item.increment` consumes the item and returns a new instance.

In `Container.increment_item` I want to replace the current item with the one returned by `Item.increment` but the compiler yells at me with a `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

In `Container.increment_item` `self` is `mut` so I can mutate its fields, I don't understand why the compiler doesn't allow me to do it.

I know that I can make `Container.increment_item` consumes `self` and return a new object, like `Item.increment` does, and it works, but I would like to understand why I'm getting the error and how can I fix it when I really can't consume the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Item::increment` expects `self` by value, it moves the `Item` on which it is invoked.
- `Container::increment_item` takes `&mut self` by reference, it allows you to mutate `self`, but it does not allow you to take ownership of `self` (or of any of its parts).
- When you invoke `self.item.increment(amount)`, you are trying to pass `self.item` by value, thus moving ownership to the `Item::increment` function, but you are not allowed to do this with references to values that you don't own.

Just pass `self` to `Item::increment` by mutable reference, that's exactly what mutable references are for:

```
struct Item {
    x: u32,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn increment(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        self.x += amount;
    }
}

struct Container {
    item: Item,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn increment_item(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        self.item.increment(amount);
    }
}
```

If you insist on taking ownership of `Item`, then you could use `mem::replace`:

```
use std::mem;

struct Item {
    x: u32,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn increment(self, amount: u32) -> Self {
        Item { x: self.x + amount }
    }
}

struct Container {
    item: Item,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn increment_item(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        self.item = mem::replace(&mut self.item, Item { x: 0 }).increment(amount);
    }
}
```

but it seems unnecessarily complicated in this case.

Comment: _(or of any of its parts)_ Thanks, that was what I missed about ownership in structs, now I understand the error. Unfortunately in my real world case `Item` (and therefore `Item::increment`) comes from a third-party API so I can't just make it `mut` there, also it's not easy to construct a new instance of `Item` so the `mem::replace` solution it's not what I were expecting.

I'm going to open a new question about this specific case.

Answer (score -1):

`increment_item()` takes `Container` by  reference and `item` cannot be moved (or "consumed") while it is behind a reference since `increment()` takes `Item` by value. Quickest way to fix this is to make `Item` a `Copy` type. This will trigger a copy and not a move (i.e consume). [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4825186dd85643e0c47d1b4eac9ecae3)

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Item {
    x: u32,
}
```

For more, please refer [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)

Comment: kindly explain the downvote!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you can't make every item copy. Therefore it's not a solution for every usecase.