# How to replace the value of a struct field without taking ownership

Tags: rust, ownership

(Following ["cannot move out of borrowed content" when replacing a struct field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54267665/648661))

I have a third-party API where one struct have a method that consumes the instance and returns a new instance; I want to wrap this API in my own wrapper and abstract away the detail that the struct is consumed in the operation.

This example explains what I'm trying to achieve:

```rust
// Third-party API
struct Item {
    x: u32,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn increment(self, amount: u32) -> Self {
        Item { x: self.x + amount }
    }
}

// My API
struct Container {
    item: Item,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn increment_item(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        // This line causes "cannot move out of borrowed content" but this is exactly what I want to do
        self.item = self.item.increment(amount);
    }
}
```

While now I understand the error I'm wondering how can I implement this without taking ownership of `self` inside `Container::increment_item`.

Proposed solutions:

- **Change `Item::increment` to take `&mut self` instead of `self`:** I can't, `Item::increment` comes from a crate.
- **Use `mem::replace` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54268089/648661)):** Unfortunately constructing an `Item` instance it's not that easy, and to be honest I don't completely understand how the `mem::replace` solutions works.
- **Change `Container::increment_item` to take `self` instead of `&mut self`:** I don't want to consume the `Container` instance in the process, I'm trying to design my wrapper to be as ergonomic as possible and abstract away *completely* the fact that `Item` must be consumed when changing it.

Some ideas on how to do it? Or am I trying an impossible design in Rust?

Comment: Why not changing the signature of `increment_item` to take `self` instead of `&mut self`?

Comment: @hellow Because I don't want to consume the `Container` instance in the process, I'm trying to design my wrapper to be as ergonomic as possible and abstract away *completely* the fact that `Item` must be consumed when changing it; I'll add it to the description.

Comment: You can use an `Option<Item>` to `mem::replace` it with `None`, or you can `mem::replace` with a zeroed memory zone (unsafe).

Comment: @Boiethios: Why `mem::replace`, just `take`! :)

Comment: See the duplicate, and specifically [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370552/147192), which illustrates how to use an option for your use case.

Comment: See also [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423); [How do I move out of a struct field that is an Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031002/155423).

Comment: @Caio how would that help? OP specifically states that they don't want to take `self` by value.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry for the bad comment. It should be an additional `ContainerBuilder` struct instead. Deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an `Option`:

- use `take` to take ownership of the item,
- then assign back `Some(...)`.

If a panic occurs while the `Option` is empty, this is perfectly safe. No double-destruction occurs, and the container can even remain usable if you so desire.

Or in code:

```
// Third-party API
struct Item {
    x: u32,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn increment(self, amount: u32) -> Self {
        Item { x: self.x + amount }
    }
}

// My API
struct Container {
    item: Option<Item>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn increment_item(&mut self, amount: u32) {
        let item = self.item.take().unwrap();
        self.item = Some(self.item.increment(amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way to do this, but I dislike to use `unwrap` each time I must use the field.

Comment: Ey this looks like a good solution, I'll try it and accept the answer when I have some time, thanks!

Comment: Just asking to learn, are we going to give answer the questions even they are duplicate? Or do we just flag them as duplicate?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan: It's better to flag as duplicate and not answer; but if a duplicate is only uncovered after an answer is made, then so be it. I should have waited for Shepmaster to check the question first, he's got a built-in duplicate detector ;)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I am recently started actively contributing SO as habbit and I can say that he is pretty much idol to me in here rust community :)